# Filter angular data by array of ids

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework

I have a json file containing my data

```
[{"id":"349","title":"event 1"},{"id":"350","title":"event 2"},{"id":"351","title":"event 3"}]
```

A user can save events to local storage and are saved in an array

```
$storage.myEvents = ["349","350"]
```

I display all events on the page with;

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-right item-brown" ui-sref="detail({id: event.id})" ng-repeat="event in events track by event.id ">
        <h2 class="positive"><b>{{event.title}}</b></h2> 
</ion-item>
```

I want to show just the users events they have stored in `$storage.myEvents` but my filter doesn't work

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-right item-brown" ui-sref="detail({id: event.id})"
  ng-repeat="event in events track by $index | filter: {id: $storage.myEvents }">
```

it gives the error `Error:  filter:notarray Expected array but received: 0`, if I query the local storage I get

```
localStorage["ngStorage-myEvents"]
"["349","350"]"
```

if I change the filter to

```
 filter: {id: JSON.parse($storage.myEvents)}
```

I still get the same error...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom filter.

```
  $scope.myFilter = function (e) {
    var s = $scope.$storage.myEvents;
    if (s.indexOf(e.id) != -1) return true;
    return false;
  }

  <ion-item class="item-icon-right item-brown" ui-sref="detail({id: event.id})" 
       ng-repeat="event in events | filter: myFilter track by $index">
```

Answer (score 0):

thats a repeater

```
event in events track by event.id
```

it seems like there are events with same event.id (mb some with undefined id) in array.